# increment nested JSONDBObject value in java

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I have a BasicDBObject of following structure in JAVA

```
"category_id": "keyboard",
    "ontology_id": "mobile",
    "path": "#mobile#keyboard",
    "date": "2013/008/01 12:30:00",
    "hour": {
        "12": {
            "total_docs": 1
        }
    }
```

I need to increment total_docs value by 1 but i am not able to access that object. How should i proceed in this case

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to access that object". Do you have an exception to provide here?

Comment: How come you cannot access that object? Assuming you are trying to update an object in the database (not an object in your application), have you tried db.collection.update(find_query, {$inc: {"hour.12.total_docs": 1}}) ?

Comment: @MarkBramnik i mean to in mongo console we can access "total_docs" like "hour.12.total_docs". how to do the similar in java

Comment: @randunel can i do the same in java from mongo console i am able to do the same

Comment: Great! The problem statement is clear. Now, could you add what you have tried until now?

Comment: @Jayz till now i have tried in this way BasicDBObject total_docs = new BasicDBObject().append("$inc",new BasicDBObject().append("total_docs", 1));

Comment: are you using spring framework?

Comment: nope, it's plain java code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

never mind, we just need to append the value in string and it's done